# Ansible - using for loops inside user module

Tags: ansible

I recently discovered the use of for loops in Ansible and was very excited about it. 
Tries to use it inside the debug module and it worked superfine, but when I am trying to use the same inside "user" module, the control flow is not able to identify the "name" keyword of user module. Below is my poetry,

```
- hosts: testservers
  tasks:
  - name: Setting user facts
    set_fact:
      username: "{{ lookup('ini', 'name section=userDetails file=details.ini') }}"
      userpass: "{{ lookup('ini', 'password section=userDetails file=details.ini') }}"

  - name: User creation
    become: true
   # debug:
   #    msg: |
   #     {% for x,y in item.1,item.2 %}
   #     {{ x }} is the username and its password is {{ y }}
   #     {% endfor %}
   # with_items: 
   #     - { 1: "{{ username.split(',') }}", 2: "{{ userpass.split(',') }}" }
    user: |
      {% for x,y in item.1,item.2 %}
      name: "{{ x }}"
      password: "{{ y }}"
      {% endfor %}
    with_items:
        - { 1: "{{ username.split(',') }}", 2: "{{ userpass.split(',') }}" }
```

Details.ini file contents below

```
#User basic details
[userDetails]
name=vasanth,vasanthnagkv
password=vasanth12,pass2
```

The commented part above works fine. but the uncommented part throws the below error

```
failed: [10.0.0.47] (item={1: [u'vasanth', u'vasanthnagkv'], 2: [u'vasanth12', u'pass2']}) => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "append": false, 
            "create_home": true, 
            "force": false, 
            "move_home": false, 
            "non_unique": false, 
            "remove": false, 
            "ssh_key_bits": 0, 
            "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on APUA-02", 
            "ssh_key_type": "rsa", 
            "state": "present", 
            "system": false, 
            "update_password": "always"
        }
    }, 
    "item": {
        "1": [
            "vasanth", 
            "vasanthnagkv"
        ], 
        "2": [
            "vasanth12", 
            "pass2"
        ]
    }, 
    "msg": "missing required arguments: name"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/admin/ansiblePlaybooks/userCreation/userCreate.retry

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.0.0.47                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Appreciate any kind of help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `user: |` means your passing a string to **user** module using the block style indicator: https://yaml-multiline.info/)

Since Ansible will just treat it as a string, you are not passing the required `name` parameter to the `user` module

Try splitting the names after the lookup in the first task so you can have the names and passwords list:

```
- name: Setting user facts
  set_fact:
    username: "{{ lookup('ini', 'name section=userDetails file=details.ini').split(',') }}"
    userpass: "{{ lookup('ini', 'password section=userDetails file=details.ini').split(',') }}"
```

Once you have both the username and password list, you can use both variables by:

```
    - user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        password: "{{ userpass[index] }}"
      loop: "{{ username }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index
```

Comment: How does 'item' point to username list In your example ? Shouldn't you pass a with statement ? And also, how does the index variable increment on each iteration.? Does it happen implicitly ?

Comment: It's explained here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html:

    `Before 2.5 Ansible mainly used the with_<lookup> keywords to create loops, 
    the loop keyword is basically analogous to with_list.`